# apt-get update relocation error

Tags: apt, 17.10

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 (artful).  After I upgraded from 17.04, my apt-get update stopped working.  I already installed [libstdc++6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libs/libstdc++6) (32-bit & 64-bit) and its dependencies like other posts for Ubuntu 16 suggest.  I reinstalled [libgnutls30](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libs/libgnutls30) as well.

This is the output of apt-get update:

```
root@adam-desktop:~/Downloads# apt-get update
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: symbol gnutls_session_set_verify_cert, version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined in file libgnutls.so.30 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: symbol gnutls_session_set_verify_cert, version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined in file libgnutls.so.30 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: symbol gnutls_session_set_verify_cert, version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined in file libgnutls.so.30 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: symbol gnutls_session_set_verify_cert, version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined in file libgnutls.so.30 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: symbol gnutls_session_set_verify_cert, version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined in file libgnutls.so.30 with link time reference
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/artful/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wipe the disk and reinstall Ubuntu 17.10.  I tried the recovery option first, but the relocation error was still there.